# Pentaho DI - How to use "all" results from prior step in the next step as an "IN" query

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have input from a tableA in database A that I would like to join to another tableB in database B.

These were my two options:

1. Use Database Join: For each input from table in database A, run the
   join query in database B.
2. Use two Input tables (talbeA + tableB) and do merge join on key.

I went with option #1 as I want to avoid reading in tableA and tableB in entirety.

My question is:
How can I use all results from a prior step as one "IN" query?

*For instance*

```
select *
from tableB b
where b.id IN (all_rows_from_prior_step)
```

*versus (where it runs for each input row)*

```
select *
from tableB b
where b.id = ?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'Group by' to flatten the rows into one row with a field 'all_rows_from_prior_step' of comma separated ids (Group field: empty, Name: all_rows_from_prior_step, Subject: id, Type: 'Concatenate strings separated by ,'). Next, use a 'User Defined Java Expression' to build the sql query:

`"select * from tableB b where b.id IN (" + all_rows_from_prior_step + ")"`

Last, use 'Dynamic SQL row' to run the query. The template sql could be

`select * from tableB b where 1=0`

Comment: I followed as detailed in your explanation, however, if I have ten input rows, I ended up with ten IN query being ran at the end. It looks like 'Concat Fields' is not flattening the rows into 1 row for me. I played with different options in 'Concat Fields' but no dice.

Comment: Sorry, my explanation was wrong. See updated explanation.

Comment: Updated explanation is doing exactly what I was looking for, I end up with one nice IN query!